# "habit, vêtement, tenue" What is the difference between these synonyms?

Tags: choix-de-mot, synonymes

I’d like to find out about when to use each one.

> Je projette d’acheter de nouveaux habits.
>
> Je projette d’acheter de nouveaux vêtements.
>
> Je projette d’acheter de nouvelles tenues.

Comment: Je projet**t**e...

Answer (score 2):

"Habits" and "vêtements" have the exact same meaning to me. I'd say that "vêtements" sounds maybe a bit more formal than "habits" but both are used fairly commonly.

"Tenue" on the other hand has a slightly different meaning : it is used to refer to an ensemble. A "tenue" is the sum of the "vêtements" that you are wearing (trousers and a shirt is a "tenue" or a skirt, tights and a blouse...). It is mostly used to refer to the set of clothes for a specific event.

> "J'ai trouvé une tenue pour la soirée."

Comment: A **squirt**? Don't google that.

Comment: Oh my god sorry for that, thanks for the edit !

Answer (score 1):

"Tenue" is a set of clothes with a specific purpose: tenue de soirée, tenue de combat, tenue de travail, tenue de ski/tennis...

"habits" is mostly used for the outer layer: jacket, trousers, skirt, sweater... while "vêtements" encompasses everything: shirt, underwear, socks.

Comment: To complete, "habits" will mean "business clothes, not casual" in Quebec and is unusual in France.